# Transaction cost not showing on Phantom

Tags: wallet, phantom

For a couple of weeks now, I find the message "No changes impacting asset ownership found" in my Phantom wallet for every transaction with Solana Devnet. The transaction result is Succesfull but Phantom doesn't show the amount on the approval window.

Is it me or this happened to someone else?
Is it a Phantom or a Solana issue?
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the network from main net to devnet.? Probably go to settings and then change it to dev net.